# What is the average response broken down by row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I've been stumped on this for a while and can't seem to find an answer.

this is my database diagram

[image]

I'm supposed to find give the command to show the average response broken down by each question. I'm sure there is some really simple solution to this but I must be over thinking it or completely missing something obvious. There are 6 questions total in the questions table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT q.id, AVG(s.survey_response)
FROM survey_questions q
INNER JOIN survey_responses s ON q.id = s.survey_question_id
GROUP BY q.id
```

Comment: omg I feel so stupid... so after all I tried all I needed was a group by statement... obviously my understanding of what group by did was confused. Thanks again so much!

Comment: as soon as I figure out how sure. Also is there any particular advantage to using an inner join over just a regular join for this?

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) is how accepting an answer works. About the inner join, it is a regular join that takes only the rows that match on the two sides of the join.:). See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/1385896) for more information on JOINS

Comment: normally I'm able to just google my question or ask someone else... this might become my go to site for programming related stuff... I might also have to start answering questions. Alright thanks again and have a good day!